# Initial boot hangs after a successful install of ParrotSec

Tags: boot, macintosh, parrotsec

I have a late 2011 Macbook Pro and I'm trying to boot Parrot Linux Security edition for the first time after a successful install.

I've edited the boot options to eliminate all options EXCEPT ro and added nomodeset. However, the boot hangs on the screen below.  It also looks like the system is logging inputs since when I moved my mouse, the last line showed up "logitech-hidpp-device 0003:....":

[image]

If I modify the boot options to radeon.modeset=0 (since the mac has an AMD Radeon graphics processor), I get the following error:

[image]

I've [tried the answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273471) as well but the boot hangs at this screen:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try this - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/273471/34720

Comment: @nwildner I've tried that as well but did not help.  The boot process hangs again on the screen I attached.